# How can I embed lists within tcolorbox correctly?

Tags: lists, margins, tcolorbox

## `tcolorbox`

I am using this package over `mdframed` because it offers a plethora of features to create robust boxes (handles single and multipage situations).

How can I embed lists e.g. description lists within `tcolorbox` environments, yet have the right alignment automatically adjust itself to be flush with the rest of the content in the `tcolorbox` environment.

The solution should robust in that it can handle all embedded lists environments.

## Problem

The embedded list's text box extends beyond the box (frame) of the `myexample` environment itself.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,lipsum} 
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
 \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable} 
 \newcounter{myexample} 

 \colorlet{examplecolor}{gray}
 \usepackage{enumitem}

 \setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=15pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-5pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

 \newtcolorbox[use counter=myexample]{myexample}{%
    % myexample Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    title={\large Example \thetcbcounter},
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
    attach boxed title to top left,
    % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,overlay={}},
    coltitle=examplecolor,fonttitle=\Large\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=3mm,top=2pt,
        breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: first page
    overlay first={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: middle page
    overlay middle={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: last page
    overlay last={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },%
    }

 \begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-3]

\begin{description}
    \item [Fruit] Fruits tend to be sweet.
     \begin{description}
        \item [Apples] Here is some text.
             \begin{myexample}
             \lipsum[1]
             \begin{itemize}
                \item \lipsum[1]
            \end{itemize}
             \end{myexample}
    \end{description}
 \end{description}
\lipsum[1] % <-- Nothing to do with question, but I noticed that this text is white/invisible and I do not know why.

 \end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While removing `parbox=false` avoids the problem, it also changes the formatting inside the box -- most notably the parskip. So I would probably only reset `\@totalleftmargin`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item [Fruit] Fruits tend to be sweet.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false,before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt]
     blabl\par blbla
     \begin{itemize}
       \item\lipsum[1]
     \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
     \begin{tcolorbox}[]
     blabl\par blbla
     \begin{itemize}
       \item\lipsum[1]
     \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I am not sure I see the difference in your example, however.  Ahh now I do. "the blabl blbla"..So then, the `parskip` is inherited from the global `parskip`, correct? This is because the content is not limited by another scope (a parbox)…

Comment: No it is not a scoping problem. A normal \parbox (and minipage) actively resets \parskip to zero (and some other values too). `parbox=false` avoids this, but imho it should better reset `\@totalleftmargin` in any case @ThomasSturm do you agree?

Comment: I was wondering... why would one want a `\parskip` inside a box?

Comment: @HarishKumar: When as in this question tcolorbox is used to add a margin marker is would imho look odd if the parskip is different in the text then in the surrounding.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree that `parbox=false` should reset `\@totalleftmargin` automatically.  I think that this should also reset `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` - at least that seems to be no harm.

Answer (score 5):

This is what the manual says about `/tcb/parbox` key

[image]

Obey the manual, you don't need this key to be false here for good.

Remove `parbox=false` from the definition of `myexample`.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
 \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
 \newcounter{myexample}

 \colorlet{examplecolor}{gray}
 \usepackage{enumitem}

 \setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=15pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-5pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

 \newtcolorbox[use counter=myexample]{myexample}{%
    % myexample Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    title={\large Example \thetcbcounter},
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
    attach boxed title to top left,
    % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,overlay={}},
    coltitle=examplecolor,fonttitle=\Large\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=3mm,top=2pt,
        breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: first page
    overlay first={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: middle page
    overlay middle={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: last page
    overlay last={\draw[examplecolor,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west); },%
    }

 \begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-3]

\begin{description}
    \item [Fruit] Fruits tend to be sweet.
     \begin{description}
        \item [Apples] Here is some text.
             \begin{myexample}
             \lipsum[1]
             \begin{itemize}
                \item \lipsum*[1]
            \end{itemize}
             \end{myexample}
    \end{description}
 \end{description}
\lipsum[1] % <-- Nothing to do with question, but I noticed that this text is white/invisible and I do not know why.

 \end{document}
```

[image]